# Autocomplete/Intellisense for For Columns in PGAdmin III

Tags: pgadmin

I recently discovered in PGAdmin III that you can autocomplete/activate intellisense by hitting Ctrl+Space.  This however only seems to work for tables.  Is there a way to trigger intellisense for column names as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

pgAdmin 4 seems to autocomplete columns when using dot notation. So hitting Ctrl+Space after

```
select * from table1 where table1.
```

will list all available columns.

Answer (score 8):

If you like intellisense and other sweet features (as me) you can try to use "[SQL Manager **Lite** for PostgreSQL](https://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/postgresql/manager)", it is free. I use both (SQL Manager **Lite** hasn't queries-graphbuilder )

*currently available for windows only*

Comment: Windows only solution :(

Comment: Sure wish there was a tool that did it all well!